# Conceptual question about uniformly picking vertices in graphs

Tags: probability, probability-theory, graph-theory

The precise question is the following: consider a bipartite Graph $G=A \cup B$. If I pick a vertex $v$ in $A$ uniformly at random, what is the probability that a given vertex $w \in B$ is a neighbour of $v$?

My thoughts: first I note that $v$ is a neighbour of $w$ iff $w$ is a neighbour of v. So the probability that $w$ is a neighbour of $v$ is equal to the probability that $v$ is a neighbour of $w$ (right?). But then since $v$ is picked uniformly at random this probability is given by $|N(w)|/|A|$ where $N(w)$ denotes the neighbourhood of $w$.

Please help me clearify my thoughts.

Also: If my reasoning is correct, why is the following computation wrong.
      Porbability is given by $2e(G)/(n(n-1))$ i.e number of edges of $G$ divided by number of total possible edges in $G$? It makes sense to me since we are not picking edges uniformly at random but vertices. But how would you explain this formally?

Comment: Yep, sucess cases dividied by total cases.

Comment: Ok, but then I have a second question: why is the probability NOT given by $2e(G)/(n(n-1))$ i.e number of edges of $G$ divided by number of total possible edges in $G$?

Comment: because edges (existent or possible) that are unrelated to the given vertex $w$ play no role. The same holds for edges possibly present in a totally different graph $H$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct, this is just the usual "success cases divided by total cases" thing.

If one wanted to make this overly formal (and at the same time presumably less comprehensible):
We consider uniform choice from $A$, i.e., our probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$ is given by the sample space $\Omega=A$, the set of events $\mathcal F=\mathcal P(A)$, and the probability function given by $P(E)=\frac{|E|}{|A|}$ for $E\in\mathcal P(A)$  (where we sometimes also write $P(v\in E)$ instead of $P(E)$).

We are asking for the event "the chosen vertex $v$ is neighbour of the given vertex  $w$" or $$P(v\in N(w))=P(N(w)\cap A)=P(N(w))=\frac{|N(w)|}{|A|}$$
where the second equality uses the fact that $G$ is bipartite and $w\in B$.